# Stackdriver logging - Why is not my payload showing correctly in Runtime V8

Tags: google-apps-script, logging, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I add a simple log message and I see the log in Stackdriver.
But the payload is not splited to separate values.
The problem is that Payload is shown as one big string with message and payload.
I need a list of values so I can Query for ex isValid or content.

How can I get the payload to a list of values inside Stackdriver logging?

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#using_cloud_logging

```
// Log a JSON object at a DEBUG level. The log is labeled
  // with the message string in the log viewer, and the JSON content
  // is displayed in the expanded log structure under "jsonPayload".
  var parameters = {
      isValid: true,
      content: 'some string',
      timestamp: new Date()
  };
  console.log({message: 'Function Input', initialData: parameters});
```

[image]

**Update**
If downgrade project to ["runtimeVersion": "DEPRECATED_ES5"] payload work correct.
If I run project in new "Runtime Chrome V8" the payload is NOT working.

Comment: Could you use a separate console.log() for each property?

Comment: No. I need to data in one log entry. The reason is that I will add extra data to log that I need to filter on.

Comment: Here is a picture of how payload should look.
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/5085260/55723890-745dfc00-5a0a-11e9-9b64-f40868bd15b3.png

Comment: I found the problem is the "Runtime Chrome V8". 
If I disable and run with old runtime the payload works as expected.

Comment: But now alot of other stuff stop working. Is there any way to get the payload work correct with Chrome V8?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direction you expect, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same situation. In such case, I use `Logger.log` instead of `console.log`. So please modify as follows and test it again.

#### From:

```
console.log({message: 'Function Input', initialData: parameters});
```

#### To:

```
Logger.log({message: 'Function Input', initialData: parameters});
```

#### Result:

When `Logger.log` is used for the value, the following result is obtained. In this case, even when V8 runtime is enabled, the object is parsed at the Stackdriver.

[image]

#### Note:

- This is a current workaround. So when this issue was resolved, I think that you can use `console.log`. Also, I found this issue at the issue tracker.

  - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/121303464

    - This has "Fixed" status at Feb 8, 2019. But in the current stage, it seems that the issue occurs again.
  - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/133278375

#### Reference:

- [Logging](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging)

Comment: Great. Thanks.
But Logger is missing the .Warn and .Error functions?

Comment: @Henrik Thank you for replying. When I saw the official document of Class Logger, in this case, `Logger.log` has no methods for "the .Warn and .Error functions". [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger) In the current stage, I cannot still obtain the workaround for this. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: I hope Google fix this bug in console :) Thanks for you help.